# How to correctly define sysconfdir in Makefile?

Tags: make

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html

There it shows that you should write something like this:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=$(prefix)
bindir=$(exec_prefix)/bin
sysconfdir=$(prefix)/etc
```

So then when you use `make prefix="/usr"` it will correctly produce `bindir=/usr/bin`.

But then it will also produce `sysconfdir=/usr/etc` which is wrong.

How should I define `sysconfdir` correctly (so that it results in either `/usr/local/etc` or `/etc`)?  Should I also overwrite `sysconfdir` in the command line?

Or maybe I should create a `prefixroot` variable where I strip a trailing `/usr` and use that instead of `$(prefix)` for dirs that are not in `/usr`?

Or maybe create a symlink `$(prefix)/etc` -> `$(prefix:/usr=)/etc` if `prefix` contains a trailing `/usr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should override `sysconfdir`:

```
make prefix=/usr sysconfdir=/etc
```

Comment: Would you argue against the following workaround in the Makefile?: `sysconfdir = $(prefix:/usr=)/etc`.  On one hand, it simplifies usage, as the user doesn't need to specify `sysconfdir`; but on the other hand it is non-standard, and may produce unexpected results on some corner case (I can't think of such one right now).

Comment: Yes, I would argue against it. It’s non-standard, as you say, and it results in different behaviour with other prefixes (`/usr/local`, `/opt/...` etc.). IMO `sysconfdir` is a special case, never inside a prefix, so I wouldn’t introduce a special prefix just for it. `sysconfdir = /etc` on the Makefile would also make sense as far as I’l concerned (it can still be overridden).

Comment: The point of this workaround is that for `/usr/local` it does nothing (as expected), resulting in `/usr/local/etc`; for `/opt/somedir` it would result in `/opt/somedir/etc`; for `/opt/somedir/usr/otherdir/usr/` it would result in `/opt/somedir/usr/otherdir/etc` (note no trailing`/usr`).  So it only removes a trailing `/usr` and never a `/usr` that is not trailing.  Do you think there is a valid case where a the behaviour would be unwanted?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But given existing behaviour in build tools, build systems already override `sysconfdir` when they specify a `/usr` prefix anyway, and IMO `/usr/local/etc`, `/opt/somedir/etc` and so on are all wrong, system-wide configuration files should go in `/etc` regardless of the installation prefix.